# How to clone Heroku repo in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli

I am building a Node.js app on Heroku. I used my Mac to do so. Now I would like to work on the same app from my Windows 10 machine. How should I proceed to do so? I downloaded the Heroku Toolbelt cli and git bash for windows 10 but when I try to run `heroku git:clone -a myApp`, it says

```
 `WARNING
WARNING Node version must be >=8.3.0 to use the Heroku CLI
WARNING
C:\Users\ramya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\heroku-cli\node_modules\cli-engine\lib\cli.js:65
  async run() {
        ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ramya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\heroku-cli\bin\run.js:10:15)`
```

How do I pull the repo from Heroku and work on it on Win 10? I have downloaded the newest version of the Heroku cli and ran it from git bash.

Comment: Did you update Node version?

Comment: [Just because you _can_ clone from Heroku doesn't mean you should make this your primary code sharing mechanism](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app): "Heroku provides the git service primarily for deployment, and the ability to clone from it is offered as a convenience. We strongly recommend you store your code in another git repository such as GitHub and treat that as canonical." It is much better to also use GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket, TFS, or any other tool whose job it is to provide a code repository.

Comment: yes. i have the newest version of node